# HiLow game in Java

Tags: java

I have a really quick question.After reworking my code i almost have it running perfectly. I just need to reset the number of tries after the user enters Y to play again. any suggestions? Here is my code

```js
import java.util.Random;     // Random number generator class
import java.util.Scanner;    // reads user inputs

public class HiLo
{
 public static void main (String[] args)
 {
  Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  Random gen=new Random(); //using system clock to seed
  //declare variables
  int max;
  int answer = 0;
  int guess = 0;
  int numberOfTries = 0 ;
  char again;

  do

  {
   System.out.print ("Enter the maximum number in the range: ");
   max = Keyboard.nextInt();

   System.out.println("\nI am thinking of a number between 0 and "+max);
    answer = gen.nextInt((max-0) + 1 ) - 0;

   while (guess != answer)


   {
      System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
     guess = Keyboard.nextInt();
     numberOfTries++;

   if(guess == -999)
   {
    System.out.print("The number is: ");
    System.out.print(answer);
    System.out.println(",Thank you for playing!!!");

     System.exit(0);

      }else if (guess <= 0 || guess > max)

   {
     System.out.println("You need to use a number that's between 0 & "+max);
     numberOfTries--;

   }else if (guess < answer )//If guess is less than the answer

   {
    System.out.println ("Your guessed too low! \nTry again:");

   }else if (guess > answer )//If guess is more than the answer

   {
    System.out.println ("Your guess is too high! \nTry again:");

   }
   else;
      }
      //display result


    System.out.println ("YOU WIN!");
    System.out.println("It took you " + numberOfTries + " tries!") ;
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print( "Do you want to play again(Y/N)?");
     Keyboard.nextLine();
     again=Keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);





  }while ( again == 'y' );



 } // end of class

} //end of main
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not reset the `numberOfTries` before the `while (guess != answer)`?

```
numberOfTries = 0;
while (guess != answer) 
{...
```

Comment: I had just fixed it before reading this, thank you for the help though! it was a really quick fix!